# What's the most efficient way to clear out a collection of ActiveRecord objects?

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have a collection of AR objects in a loop, that will likely be run many times, so I want to empty the collection at the end of each iteration.

What's the most efficient way to do that?

**Edit 1**

Here is an example of what happens when I use `.clear`:

```
1.9.3p392 :039 > t = w.tags
 => [#<Tag id: 32451, name: "c++", num_questions: 180854, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55">, #<Tag id: 32452, name: "performance", num_questions: 28543, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55">, #<Tag id: 32453, name: "optimization", num_questions: 10021, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55">, #<Tag id: 32454, name: "language-agnostic", num_questions: 5942, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55">, #<Tag id: 32455, name: "branch-prediction", num_questions: 28, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:55">, #<Tag id: 32456, name: "books", num_questions: 2667, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:59", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:59">, #<Tag id: 32457, name: "ebook", num_questions: 263, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:59", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:59">, #<Tag id: 32458, name: "creative-commons", num_questions: 62, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:59", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:55:59">, #<Tag id: 32459, name: "json", num_questions: 39746, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:56:03", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:56:03">, #<Tag id: 32460, name: "content-type", num_questions: 874, created_at: "2013-02-25 07:56:03", updated_at: "2013-02-25 07:56:03">] 
1.9.3p392 :040 > t.clear
   (19.0ms)  BEGIN
   (85.2ms)  DELETE FROM "questions_tags" WHERE "questions_tags"."question_id" = 10053 AND "questions_tags"."tag_id" IN (32451, 32452, 32453, 32454, 32455, 32456, 32457, 32458, 32459, 32460)
   (36.5ms)  COMMIT
 => [] 
1.9.3p392 :041 > t
 => [] 
1.9.3p392 :042 > t
 => [] 
1.9.3p392 :043 > w.tags
 => []
```

Answer (score 3):

[The builtin method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-clear):

```
 your_array.clear
```

Comment: is that better than just doing `t = []`? Why or why not? Actually...just tried this and it seems that it actually deletes the record in the DB - not the records in the array...which is not what I wanted to do.

Comment: Is deleting the records from the DB an expected behavior? For what it's worth, I am using Rails.

Comment: I can't see how it would save your object

Comment: I don't want to delete the records from the DB. I just want to empty the array. I am going to update the question with actual code and examples. Done....check update to question.

Comment: then it's not an array, it's an active record relation. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Ahh..good point. So what's the best way to clear out a collection of AR objects?

Comment: See doc: `collection.clear`: Removes every object from the collection. This does not destroy the objects.

Comment: But that's pretty much exactly what I did. I did `.clear` on my `t` collection and it removed the objects and deleted them from the db.

Comment: Was that a snarky comment or are you being sincere?

Comment: I can't try now so I can't check. Actually I'm very surprised the doc could be wrong but it's not impossible

Comment: Well...it could be right, and I am doing something wrong - but from the code I have pasted above, does it seem like I am doing something wrong? I would love to be able to try something else, but not quite sure what to try.

Comment: yep, can't see anything buggy in your code. Maybe a dependent: :destroy is doing it's job

Comment: Yeh I looked for that, after looking at the docs, and I don't have any. The most I have is something like this: `has_and_belongs_to_many :questions, uniq: true`

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [Rails doc on associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html). The `clear` method is not the `Array#clear`, it's overriden by Rails.

I would just copy the elements in the association, this will ensure that the association will be lazy loaded, with something like:

```
tags = w.tags.collect{|t| t}
tags.clear
```